# TFS2015 copying file to target machines without DOMAIN

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, ms-release-management

I have a problem with creating proper task in TFS 2015 to copy zip file from Agent server to multiple hosts which are in DMZ (no domain).

"Powershell on target machine" is the only task which accepts ./username rather than (machinename/username) but it is using WinRm which is running on local system and have no access to the target machine.

When I use "Windows Machine File Copy" this one accepts username only in format machinename/username and I want to specify same local account for all machines.

Anyway I kind of stuck thought about adding permissions for the agent computer account on target servers but they are not in domain so will not work.

Also I cannot run script on target machines to pull files from agent as there is firewall between, I can only connect from agent to target.

Comment: No FTP available?

Comment: Hi Mike, not allowed :) but was hoping I can sort it by UNC

Comment: Why not use "Windows Machine File Copy"  task? Admin Login requires the username of either a domain or a local administrative account on the target host(s). You can create local administrative accounts for each target machine.

Answer (score 2):

If using `Windows Machine File Copy task`, you can create local administrative accounts for each target machine. As `Admin Login` requires the username of either a domain or a local administrative account on the target host(s).

Or you may try to use the [Copy Files step](https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/build/steps/utility/copy-files) and the [Publish Build Artifacts step](https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/build/steps/utility/publish-build-artifacts), to drop the files to a file share (UNC file path).